# Log file (not found) / Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-cli

While debugging an app on `Heroku`, I get this kind of message in the log console:

```
............
 app[web.1]: 
 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2017-08-19T03_00_34_428Z-debug.log
 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

My problem is that I don't know how to find this file:

**/app/.npm/_logs/2017-08-19T03_00_34_428Z-debug.log**

The given path taken as is, is obviously wrong and wherever I look I do not see it.

Anyone knows where the file is?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question. Not able to find this log file. 
However, you can view the log by setting it to verbose

```
heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=verbose
```

and then running `git push heroku master`